# Converting strings in Android bluetoothchat

Tags: java, android

I am trying to take serial data from a TTL output device, pass it through a JY-MCU dongle and read it on my Android phone.  The data is sent as a 4 digit ASCII decimal number followed by carriage return and line feed.

Using BluetoothChat, I can see the transmitted number correctly on the phone but I want to manipulate the number within the app and then send the result of the manipulation to the screen.

I only need to read the data, not send it.

Looking at the code in `BluetoothChat.java` I thought I would need to convert the string created in MESSAGE_READ to an `Integer` value, manipulate this integer number, convert it back to a string and send this result to the display.
Is this the right way to go about this?  I have tried using `Integer.parseInt()` and `String.valueOf`() but without success.

I can post a simple section of the code showing what I am trying to do but thought I might be making a simple mistake which somebody can point out first.

Thanks for any suggestions
David

```
 byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
 // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
 String readMessage = new String(readBuf,0, msg.arg1);
 //remove any leading zero's
 String readMessages = readMessage.replaceAll("^0*", "");
 //remove any leading zero's
 // Declare Integer
 int newMessage;
 // give the integer a value
 newMessage = Integer.valueOf(readMessages);
 // try some simple division
 newMessage = newMessage / 100;
 // back to a string
 String finalMessage = Integer.toString(newMessage);
 // display the result
 mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + finalMessage);
```

Stacktrace

01-25 18:09:12.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 18:09:12.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5413): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
01-25 18:09:12.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5413):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
01-25 18:09:12.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5413):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
01-25 18:09:12.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5413):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)

Comment: Could you add an example of the string are you reading? Did you try to right trim the string to remove blank chars before parsing?

Comment: Hi Trapo, thanks for looking at this.  If I check the string being sent from the device with terminal emulation I see 0000972.  This is correct as it is based on a cycle time for an object to pass two sensors and is what I would expect.  I have not trimed this string as you suggested and I wonder if this is the cause of all my problems!  I really need to set it up to remove the unused zero characters I guess.

Comment: Following?? Please edit question adding your code

Comment: Hi Trapo, sorry about the tardy response - work got in the way.  The sample I've posted works fine if I comment out the sections where I try to get the string into and Integer and convert it back again.

Comment: Post stacktrace in error case, please

Comment: and, if you are using something like Eclipse, the value of readMessages and readMessage after assignment

Comment: readMessage shows"0" and readMessages shows "" which explains why I get the error I guess but I am still not understanding why these values are present in the code when I try to covert the string but do not give an error when I comment the conversion sections out.

Comment: Hi, could somebody explain why I have 2 negative marks?  I am new to this and would like to avoid wasting anybodies time with dumb questions.  I did try to research my problem before posting and have been trying to find my own solutions before asking here. Regards, david

Comment: About the negative marks. I won't worry too much about them if the question is not closed and it's still possible to receive an answer. Do not forget that your main goal is to get solved something that you cannot resolved on your own. If you think that question does not deserve negative vote, just raise the flag for the moderator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you are using is not correct as you can wonder by the fact that it returns "" (empty string) when something like "00" or "0" is the input. I suggest you to use the regular expression in the code below.

For your convenience I give you a simple test program to check if the regexp fullfil your needs. Feel free to add more tests if you are in doubt.

```
package stackoverflow.answers;

public class ParsingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Result is " + extractInteger("010"));
        System.out.println("Result is " + extractInteger("1010"));
        System.out.println("Result is " + extractInteger("0001"));
        System.out.println("Result is " + extractInteger("0000"));
        System.out.println("Result is " + extractInteger("11A0"));

    }

    private static Integer extractInteger(String s) {
        Integer i = null;
        String t = s.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
        try {
            i = Integer.valueOf(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // to be sure you return always something
            // null could be other value returned
            // in that case use a finally
            return 0;
        }
        return i;
    }

}
```

Pay attention that I prefer to return 0 when the parsing has some problem, you could decide to return null or a different integer (-1?).

Comment: about the fact that put comments avoid you error, you was not so clear. What do you exactly commented out?

Comment: Replacing finalMessages with readMessages in the last line and removing (by // ) the code in between means that I simply take the string from the buffer (in the test case this is 0000972) and strip the 0's to give readMessages a value of 972. This is then added by the + readMessages and sent to the display.  This works perfectly so I know that the value of readMessages is 972 before I try to convert it to an Integer.  Once again, thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: be sure you have the e.printstacktrace(); line. Put yourself in 972 case and post stacktrace.

Comment: Regex did it! please accept my eternal gratitude trapo for putting me on the right track.  I think your first post about stripping the blanks was bang on the money.  I simply change the code to remove the zeros with String newMessage = readMessage.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""); and all was well.  Really cannot thank you enough.